# Chrome won't loads policies

Tags: google-chrome, policy

I'm trying to follow this procedure on Chrome's documentation:

http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start

Yet no policy is loaded by chrome. I tried to create the policies/managed and policies/recomended in /opt/google/chrome also but couldn't load the policies.

Is there any special configuration I have to make in order to load Chrome's policies ?

How can I know for sure what is the right place to put the policy file ?

This is part of a WIP trying to solve this question: [Chrome Certificate Selection appears multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848786/chrome-certificate-selection-appears-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be some cache or wrong parameter problem. As I discovered in Chrome discussion forum here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-discuss

in linux, Chrome and Chromiun have the same dir for policies, which is:

/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed

if you put a valid file there it will load it. Double check the commas and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I placed my setting in

```
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/managed_policies.json
```

The contents look like this:

```
{
“ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox”: true
}
```

The file and all parent directories are readable by all users.
I tried reloading Chrome's policies via the url chrome://policy/ as well as restarting the browser and even the entire machine, but to no avail.

I am on Chrome 80 and Centos 7

What am I missing?

Thanks,
frank

Answer (score 0):

/etc/chromium/policies/managed

this path worked for Chromium